# Как отправить данные так-же как при переходе по ссылке через html тег 'a'?

Tags: php, html

Как отправить данные так-же как при переходе по ссылке через html тег ?

Есть поле для ввода. После его заполнения, по нажатию кнопки enter, данные должны отпарвиться. Если использовать `form`то даные не так отправляются как нужно, и я не могу получить значение. Так как нужно отправляются через тег `<a>`, но в него нельзя вводить значения как в `input`.

```
<form action="http://hostname/index.php">
  <input type="search" name="Поиск">
</form>
```

Comment: Как вам нужно и как отправляются через форму?

Comment: @Daniel Shatz Нужно так-же как отправляет html  тег`a`, но через форму. <a href="basic/web/index.php?r=admin_panel/access/access/index&page=1">

Answer (score 2):

Так как нужно, это через GET?

```
<form action="http://hostname/index.php" method="GET">
 Поиск:  <input type="text" name="search">
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

по клику на кнопке перейдет на ссылку вида http://hostname/index.php?search=<значение>
(см. http://htmlbook.ru/html/form)

или вы другое имели ввиду?

Comment: У меня есть адрес - `basic/web/index.php?r=admin_panel/access/access/index&page=1`, нужно перейти по нему + добавить значение к этой ссылки - `&page2=2`

Comment: эмм, <form action="basic/web/index.php?r=admin_panel/access/access/index&page=1&page2=2" method="GET">...

Comment: Нужно передать значение из импута

Comment: ну так в моем же ответе, где input с именем "search", его значение и встанет в строку в виде "...&search=значение"